# In dplyr how does the sql builder work?

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

In R, we can have the following expression:

```
tbl(con, "table1") %>% filter(col1 > 12)
```

which executes

```
select * from table1 where col1 > 12
```

But if you have tbl(con, "table1"), it executes select * from table.

How does the first function tbl(con, "table1") know that it has additional functions chained to it, and needs to wait for the chain to end before it build the proper sql query and execute the command. Yes, I know it uses lazy evaluation, but I haven't been able to write a simple toy example that will build a string in the same way

i.e.

```
shoppingList("I need to get")
```

printing out "I need to get nothing"

and

```
shoppingList("I need to get") %>% item("apples") %>% item("oranges")
```

printing out "I need to get apples and oranges"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the thing that is confusing you is that the dplyr functions `tbl` and `filter` don't actually send any code to the database for execution. When you run

```
tbl(con, "table1") %>% filter(col1 > 12)
```

what is returned is a tbl_dbi object that contains a sql query. When you run this line of code interactively in R the returned tbl_dbi object is then passed to the `print` function. In order for the tbl_dbi to be printed the query must be executed in the database. You can see this by saving the output to a variable.

```
q <- tbl(con, "table1") %>% filter(col1 > 12)
class(q)
```

In the above two lines nothing was sent to the database. The `tbl` function returned a tbl_dbi object and filter modified that tbl_dbi object. Finally the result was saved to the variable `q`.
When we print `q` then the SQL is sent to the database. So the `tbl` function does not need to know about any other dplyr functions that are called after it (like `filter` in this case). It behaves the same no matter what. It always returns a tbl_dbi object.

Now how dbplyr builds up more complex queries from simpler ones is beyond me.

Here is some code that implements your example.

```
library(dplyr)

shoppingList <- function(x){
     stopifnot(is.character(x))
     class(x) <- c("first", "shoppingList", class(x))
     x
}

item <- function(x, y){
     if("first" %in% class(x)){
          out <- paste(x, y)
     } else {
          out <- paste0(x, " and ", y)
     }
     class(out) <- c("shoppingList", class(out))
     out
}

print.shoppingList <- function(x){
     # code that only runs when we print an object of class shoppingList
     if("first" %in% class(x)) x <- paste(x, "nothing")
     print(paste0("***", x, "***"))
}

shoppingList("I need to get") 
#> [1] "***I need to get nothing***"

shoppingList("I need to get") %>% item("apples") %>% item("oranges")
#> [1] "***I need to get apples and oranges***"
```

But how does `print` know to send SQL to the database? My (oversimplified) conceptual answer is that `print` is a generic function that will behave differently depending on the class of object passed in. There are actually many `print` functions. In the example above I created a special print function for objects of class *shoppingList*. You could imagine a special `print.tbl_dbi` function that knows how to handle tbl_dbi objects by sending the the query they contain to the database they connect to and then printing the result. I think the actual implementation is more complicated but hopefully this provides some intuition.

Comment: I can understand the SQL query building part. But in the documentation they say that they don't execute the sql until an operation is done on the object. A quote from the site: """ It’s not until you ask for the data (e.g., by printing tailnum_delay) that dplyr generates the SQL and requests the results from the database."""

Comment: Exactly right. So to answer your question I'd say that tbl does not need to know anything about the functions chained to it since it does not execute anything in the database. It produces a SQL query/tbl_dpi object and the other chained functions modify that query/tbl_dbi.

Comment: my question I guess is if you say print(tbl), it knows to execute the sql statement. How?

Comment: I think that in reality the process of printing a tbl is complicated, but I edited my answer to hopefully provide some intuition for how it works.

Comment: So when you call print or otherwise use the var, how does it know to trigger an event?

Comment: Only certain functions trigger the event (sending SQL to the database). Those are print and collect as well as a few others. How do those functions “know” to trigger the event? Well they are written by the programmer specifically to trigger the event. In my example above I could trigger any event I want when an object of class shoppingList is printed simply by inserting the code I want to run in place of the comment “#code that only runs...”.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to look at the `collect.tbl_sql` and the `db_collect.DBIConnection` methods in dbplyr [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/blob/850363974928073be23cb32384f85ba7eb340e1b/R/tbl-sql.r#L416) and [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/blob/c0e51957a2fbeb4fe7bc93f0ed677d6d33e14828/R/db-compute.R#L88). The dbSendQuery function from the DBI package is what ultimately sends the query to the database.

Comment: I think in general I figured it out. It's using R6 classes, and it overwrites the print function, which does make a small call to the SQL Table

Comment: re: `Now how dbplyr builds up more complex queries from simpler ones is beyond me.`. It's basically just nesting select queries. You'll find those if you look at the structure of the object, with a little twist for group_by. There's not much optimization done if any, only step by step translation to sql and nesting of queries, but I guess some DBMS can optimize nested queries on server side.